# What is the specific term for the mounting plate that a case fan would screw into?

Tags: mount, fan, case

I recently rebuilt my computer and my original liquid cooling system was not compatible with the new motherboard. This lead me to putting up a 120mm case fan instead of the radiator contraption that was originally on the back of the case.

Unfortunately, I found that none of the fans have threads for screws. Instead, they appear to be designed to be screwed into a mounting plate of sorts. Searching on major retailer websites has resulted in more fans that appear to have no threads!

Please advise me what these mounting plate/fan bracket things are truly called!

Comment: They don’t have threads because of the type of screws used to screw them in. They use corse thread case fan screws and are mounted directly to the case. They basically self tap.

Comment: To reduce noise, the preferred method of mounting a fan is to not use screws at all, but use (flexible) plastic/silicone fan mounts.

Comment: @sawdust I have purchased some silicone fan mounts! Thanks for the tip!